# Loading a custom TimeZoneNameProvider in Java 8

Tags: java, timezone

I'm trying to create custom naming for a timezone in Java 8.

So I created a subclass of `java.util.spi.TimeZoneNameProvider` and implemented the required methods.
Following the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html) I have also created a file called `./src/main/resources/META-INF/services/java.util.spi.TimeZoneNameProvider` which contains a single line with the fully qualified name of my implementation. The final file in the jar file matches what I find in the documentation.

The problem I have is that it does not get loaded when I run my application or any of the junit tests.

NOTE: I also have a custom `java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider` which IS loaded. 
So SPI is working, just not for the TimeZoneNameProvider.

After some digging around I found that TimeZoneNameProvider is a subclass of LocaleServiceProvider and the SPI loading is done by `sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter`.

As far as I can tell the SPILocaleProviderAdapter loads the service by calling `java.util.ServiceLoader.loadInstalled(Class<S> service)` which is documented as

> This method is intended for use when only installed providers are
>   desired.  The resulting service will only find and load providers that
>   have been installed into the current Java virtual machine; providers on
>   the application's class path will be ignored.

So this code path explicitly does not load anything custom.

As an experiment I've created some code to force an alternative implementation to be used instead of the default SPILocaleProviderAdapter that essentially only uses a different classloader... which makes my custom naming rules active.

My question: How do I correctly load a custom TimeZoneNameProvider implementation?

Or is this a bug in Java 8 that I should report?

---

**Update: Additional info.**

I have tested my code with Java 8, 11 and 13 and in all cases it fails.

However! If I do `mvn clean package -Djava.locale.providers=JRE,SPI` then in Java 8 it still does not work and in Java 11 and 13 it suddenly works.

The Java 11 & 13 effect is apparently as intended because the [Java 13 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html) explicitly states that SPI is disabled by default.

> Applications which require implementations of the locale sensitive
>   services must explicitly specify "SPI" in order for the Java runtime
>   to load them from the classpath.

Comment: You add the custom jar file to the bootclasspath.

Comment: Yes, that is possible if you have a standalone application. If you need to run this code in something like a Hadoop cluster where the JVM is managed independent of the applications then simply putting it there is not an option.

Comment: *"putting it there"* makes it sound like you believe I was talking about placing the jar file in any particular place on disk. I'm not. The bootclasspath can be specified on the command-line. No need to mess with a managed JVM installation folder.

Comment: The problem is that in many situations I work on there is no "commandline" where I can control settings like bootclasspath or java.local.providers. Submitting a piece of code that must run in a distributed cluster (i.e. Hadoop Yarn / Flink / Beam / DataFlow / ... ) in many cases means that the application code is serialized and distributed to the nodes to run on a JVM where I do not have control over these kinds of settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8<sup>1</sup>, a [`TimeZoneNameProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/TimeZoneNameProvider.html), which is a [`LocaleServiceProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html), is a part of the Java Extension Mechanism. As the javadoc says:

> Implementations of these locale sensitive services are packaged using the [Java Extension Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/index.html) as installed extensions.

As the [Java™ Tutorials Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/) says:

> [**Installed Extensions**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html)
>
> Installed extensions are JAR files in the `lib/ext` directory of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE™) software.

> [**Download Extensions**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/download.html)
>
> Download extensions are sets of classes (and related resources) in JAR files. A JAR file's manifest can contain headers that refer to one or more download extensions. The extensions can be referenced in one of two ways:
>
> - by a `Class-Path` header
> - by an `Extension-List` header

Since the javadoc says "installed extensions", I don't know if the "download extensions" feature works for Locale Service Providers, but it's worth a try, so read the trail to see how it works, and try it out.

Otherwise you must install the jar with your custom `TimeZoneNameProvider` in the `lib/ext` directory of the JRE when you install the rest of your code.

<sup>1) The Java Extension Mechanism was eliminated in Java 9, so it'll work differently in Java 9+.</sup>