# Why is SPI disabled by default for LocaleServiceProvider in Java?

Tags: java, localization

I want to load custom Timezone naming code in my Java application as described in this question: [Loading a custom TimeZoneNameProvider in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937553/loading-a-custom-timezonenameprovider-in-java-8)

The [documentation on the LocaleServiceProvider for Java 13](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html) describes the ability to load a custom class using SPI.

> Applications which require implementations of the locale sensitive
>   services must explicitly specify "SPI" in order for the Java runtime
>   to load them from the classpath.

In Java 8 a custom LocaleServiceProvider is only loaded when it is installed on the system. In later Java versions SPI must explicitly be enabled.

My question is simply: Why?

Why is in Java the ability to do custom naming stuff so tightly hard coded and restricted so that it is only enabled when special things are done before the JVM is started?